# Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence in hadoop

Tags: java, xml, hadoop

I'm parsing XML using Hadoop, and I got the code from [here](https://github.com/ravisg/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java).

But I'm getting the following error:

> FINISH_TIME="1385387129970" HOSTNAME="DEV140"
>   ERROR="java.io.IOException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[18,3] Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8
>   sequence.

But my XML is encoded with UTF-8 only . So how can I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* this is the problem - it's at least *a* problem:

```
XMLStreamReader reader =
    XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new
        ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes()));
```

That call to `getBytes` will use the platform default encoding, rather than UTF-8.

You *could* specify `"utf-8"` as the encoding name - but it would be simpler to create a `StringReader`:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
    .createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(document));
```

Of course that may not be the only error, but it's at least something to look at.

Comment: @Backtrack We don't let Jon Skeet know. He's right. If your program doesn't work after you tried, there's a bug in your computer.

Comment: Thank you  Mr.Jon Skeet ... Really you saved my life ... Thank you lot

Comment: @MarounMaroun - sarcastically i put that comment . I was upset . But thanks a lot